# How to handle dynamic web-element for icon references in selenium webdriver. Can anyone help me out?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

In my application, dynamic elements are used which are basically icon/CSS selector references; for ex - save, delete, cancel buttons. These elements doesn't works with xpath's as i have tried with most of the ways. My reading is that the CSS selector will work for these elements. but i'm unable to find it out. Below is the HTML for the same.

Parent class is `<div class="rTableCell ActionCell">`

under this class `<a>` tag is used given like below

```
<a class="SaveRow" onclick="UpdateInlineData(event,'49b3f007-fbc5-492c-b609-8b24a3044ee1','GridDesignation','../MasterData/ManageDesignation')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Save" >
```

under this class `<i>` tag is used like given below

```
<i class="fa fa-floppy-o themeSaveIcon"></i>
<div class="rTableCell ActionCell" style="height: 88px;"><a class="SaveRow" onclick="UpdateInlineData(event,'49b3f007-fbc5-492c-b609-8b24a3044ee1','GridDesignation','../MasterData/ManageDesignation')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Save"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o themeSaveIcon"></i></a><a class="CancelRow" onclick="ResetInlineData(event,'49b3f007-fbc5-492c-b609-8b24a3044ee1','GridDesignation','../MasterData/ResetDesignation')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Cancel"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times themeCancelIcon"></i></a></div>
```

Comment: Share selectors you've already used

Comment: i have not used any. trying to find. @Andersson

Comment: So what does `These elements doesn't works with xpath's as i have tried with most of the ways` means?

Comment: I have tried with different way of xpath's like relative/absolute/parent/ancestors//sibling etc but none of them works.

Comment: So show them to avoid solutions that you've tried already

Comment: I have tried with diff combination of xpath's along with relative/absloute/parent/sibling/ancestors etc ; written my own custom xpath but nothing works. Actually it assigns a number for each instance at the end of every xpath & it keeps on changing whenever a new row is edited for any item.                                                                           For ex - When i edit any row & click on "save" button then the xpath (through xpath helper) would be "(//I[@class='fa fa-floppy-o themeSaveIcon'])[398]" .This number get changes each time when user edit any item@Andersson

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/groups/86204/86204-6246746920660897792 Please refer this link. As it has HTML screenshot attached.

Comment: There are no screenshots. Share your code and more details as for now it's not clear what is the problem

Comment: unable to attach any screenshot here. Please check the above HTML code as i'm suppose to click on element which is under the "i" tag i.e  <i class="fa fa-floppy-o themeSaveIcon"></i> . You can find the full HTML given above. or probably you can login in Linkedin for screenshot with the above link shared. @Andersson

Answer (score 0):

try action chains on selenium API
if you user python you can see this [document](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=action#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)

Comment: how one can use action chains here. which element will be referred as first element. I'm looking to click on "save" button only ? @Omid zarin

Answer (score 0):

for example you have 
xpath_element = "a xpath address"

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

hover = ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(xpath_element)
hover.click().perform()
```

you can perform more actions on hover depending on your purpose

Comment: Xpath gets changes each time. For each instance it assigns a number at the end of it. I have used xpath helper for finding this out.  For ex - When i edit any row & click on "save" button then the xpath (through xpath helper) would be "(//I[@class='fa fa-floppy-o themeSaveIcon'])[398]" .This number "398" get changes each time when user edit item . attaching link with the screenshot                                                                                                                                                         https://www.linkedin.com/groups/86204/86204-6246746920660897792

Comment: I think you should try css selectors because the position of the element will change not the class or id am I right ?